# Opposite of nullish coalescing operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, nullish-coalescing

Nullish coalescing operator allows assigning a variable if it's not `null` or `undefined`, or an expression otherwise.

```
a = b ?? other
```

It is an improvement over previously used `||` because `||` will also assign other if `b` is empty string or other falsy, but not nullish value.

However, sometimes, we also use `&&` for value assignment, for example

```
a = b && func(b)
```

where we only want to do `func` on `b` if it's not nullish, otherwise assign the nullish `b`.

Of course, `&&` checks for falsiness, not nullishness. Is there a nullish version of `&&`?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no such operator (and not even a proposal). But you can use the following instead: `a = b == null ? b : func(b)`.

Comment: double equal sign with null sounds scary

Comment: Why? It is [the way to check for nullish values](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

Comment: @f.khantsis `x == null` will *only* return `true` if `x = null` or `x = undefined`. As such, it's the exact match of the nullish coalescing behaviour which only activates for those values.

Comment: @str, if `b`is `null` it would already be truthy and that would just make `a` `null`. Do this instead: `let a = b === null ? other : func(b);`

Comment: @StackSlave "*do func on b if it's not nullish, otherwise assign the nullish b*" seems exactly what my code is doing.

Comment: Sorry for intervention, here is what TSC generates: ```const a = b !== null && b !== void 0 ? b : func(b);``` Simplifed version would be exact @f.khantsis provided:  ```b==null ? func(b): b````

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such operator and also no [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) to add one. Instead you can rely on the [standard way to check for nullish values](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison): `b == null`

```
a = b == null ? b : func(b)
```

Comment: If `b` is `false`, with this approach is treated as an undefined or null, so trigger `func(b)`

Comment: @Chu If `b` is nullish (only `null` or `undefined`), the function will *not* run. If `b` is anything else (including `false`) the function *will* run, and its result will be assigned to `a`. Try running `false == null` in your browser console.

Comment: How about `a = b == null && func(b)`? Or if your linting config forbids the use of `==`, then `a = (b === null || b === undefined) && func(b)`

Comment: Oh my, I've used so many triple equals `===` that I completely forgot about `undefined == null`.

Comment: @MattBrowne Even if your linter forbids ===, it should still allow == null as a special case. However, you end up with `false | T` in this case, which is not great (especially if you plan to use it again in the same way).

Comment: So this is similar to how we used to do `a = b != null ? b : other` before the nullish coalescing operator. It would be nice syntactic sugar to have a similar operator for `a = b == null ? b : func(b)`

Answer (score 8):

This will not answer the question since it was already answered by @str, I'm just posting this here because I don't have enough rep to comment on @Dalou's answer and don't want people to trip on that answer.

```
a = (b ?? false) && other
```

Is not the opposite of `??`, since `a` will take the value of `b` if `b` is a falsy value other than undefined/null, like `''` or `0` for example.
The opposite of `??` should set `a` to the value of `other` even if `b` is `''` or `0`.

Answer (score 5):

There's currently no such operator, as others have already pointed out. However, there are a few proposals for exactly this operator in the official TC39 discourse group:

- ['maybe' operator to complement ?? operator](https://es.discourse.group/t/maybe-operator-to-complement-operator/200)
- [Optional projection / expression operator - e.g. maybeNullish ?:: transform(maybeNullish)](https://es.discourse.group/t/optional-projection-expression-operator-e-g-maybenullish-transform-maybenullish/572)
- [[syntax] Inverse null coalescing operator](https://es.discourse.group/t/syntax-inverse-null-coalescing-operator/547)

If you're interested in bringing this into ECMA, these might be good places to start.

Answer (score 4):

ANSWER:

```
let a = 9;

if( a!==null || a!==undefined ){ /* actions */ };

if( (a??null) !== null ){ /* actions */ }
```

PROPOSAL:

```
const oo = console.log;
let a; // undefined, null

// Syntax proposal: !?
a !? oo('NOT Nullish coalescing operator');

// Logical NOT Nullish assignment:
let a = 7;
a !?= 5;
oo(a); // 5

let b, c = null;
b !?= 3;
oo(b); // undefined
c !?= 8;
oo(c); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it but here's my solution:

```js
output = typeof input === 'boolean' && "other"
```

Truth table:

```
input     -> output
--------------------
null      -> false
undefined -> false
true      -> "other"
false     -> "other"
```

Comment: Note that this will return `false` if `input` is some other value, like a string

Answer (score 0):

I just found this post today, and I thought to add my few words on it.

Although, [inverse null coalescing operator is in the proposal](https://es.discourse.group/t/syntax-inverse-null-coalescing-operator/547):

```
a = b !? func(b)
```

I don't think this proposal will be implemented and is a must have feature since we can simply get desired behaviors with `&&` and `||` operators. The add of `??` is special feature and is a must have feature. This is just my opinion.

I don't think we should wait than simply using like:

```
a = func(b??false)
```

We just need to be creative! I have used here nullish coalescing operator directly inside the function call so we avoided the need of inversing it like:

```
a = b != null && func(b) or so on
```

So, I opine to have `!?` is completely unnecessary. We just need to think it correctly.

"Something not null then have it" can be simply be denoted with nullish coalescing operator: (HAVE_IT ?? false) || (HAVE_IT ?? 0) || (HAVE_IT ?? ANYTHING_YOU_WANT_EXCEPT_NULL).